# Will there be an offline webview from local asset html-files in Flutter?

Tags: html, webview, flutter, assets

I guess this is just another feature request for Flutter presenting a local webpage as a WebView Widget - and all of it OFFLINE and originating from html, css and other asset files.

There are several Flutter plugins that are able to show a webView from a URL (being online) - but I haven't seen a solution yet for presenting a WebView from local assets offline.

A typical webpage with several pages (files and folders placed in the Flutter assets) would look like this:

```html
index.html
page1.html
page2.html
/images/img1.jpg
/images/img2.jpg
/css/p1.css
/css/p2.css
etc.
```

I read the following discussions (see links below) and more but I don't grasp from it if there will ever be the technical possibility in Flutter for an offline WebView Widget or not.

Is it just a matter of time we have to wait for a plugin-team to implement this - or will this never be possible in Flutter at all ? I would like to receive a more fundamental answer than what I am able to grasp after having played with Flutter for 5-6 weeks.

Here is some discussion I've found about the subject:

[How to display custom html instead of URL #23](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/23)

[Load HTML from assets or local files #27086](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27086)

Answer (score 4):

The `inAppWebView` plugin does this procedure to read offline html file or online:

Link to the plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview#-installing-tab-

Example:

```
InAppWebView(
    initialFile: "assets/index.html"
)
```

Where in initialFile you pass the path of your HTML file that is inside your flutter project.

Comment: i try this but it's ruined my file design ):